# Which forces keep two soap bubbles together?

Tags: forces, fluid-statics, surface-tension, bubbles

I am trying to calculate how many soap bubbles can hang together against the force of gravity, but I am not sure what forces hold them together. My guess is the surface tension, so an equation like $F=\sigma\cdot L$, but honestly I don't know if that is it. Would help a great deal!
It looks like this

[image]

Comment: CV Boys book ‘Soap Bubbles: Their colors and the forces that mold them’ is the classic book in soap bubbles and really cheap. It explains surface tension and has a lot of different experiments. I would recommend staring there.

Comment: Yeah i have already read the first 140 pages or so of it before. But I don't seem to remember an example like that where he is specifically describing the forces that keep af chain together.

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer/comment.

[Cyril Isenberg Soap Bubbles](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/ed058pA179.1) Dover Publications NY, is a beautiful popular book reference that includes sourcings from CV Boys. Several interesting problems (Minimum motor way junctions, Non symmetric soap bubbles etc.) are discussed.

Using *Goldschmitt conditions* in that book for stable bubbles formation we can estimate number of serially bubbles supported.

A static balance/ vertical equilibrium can be found by using the necessary angle $120^{\circ}$ at constant surface tension bubble junction shown in sketch. ( by meridional force resultants). Lumped mass of soapy solution (like sodium stearate) is unknown and should be assumed in any particular situation.

Calculation is relatively easy as weight of bubble segment is $\pi q h D $ where $q$ is mass per unit area of bubble, $(D,h)$ are maximum diameter and height of bubble segment. After including weight of the horizontal diaphragms also the vertical static force balance at top edge can be considered.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the comment. Sorry for the late answer.

Comment: I have tried to use the equation for surface tension to calculate what the ideal radius should be for the bubbles in series.
$F=\sigma\cdot r$ Where r is the interface between the two bubbles making it $F=\sigma\cdot 2\pi R\cdot sin(60)$ if you instead want to use the radius of the to bubbles instead(assuming they are equal in size). However this leads to the radius of the bubble being smaller than the thickness of the bubbles. Which doesn't make sense.

Comment: At diaphragm junction we take into account two pressures, two radii of curvature. Film thickness can be taken constant as a first step.